Kde plasma effects that show a UI are broken after update to plasma 6 on arch linux arm
When KDE Plasma 6 became available on the Arch Linux ARM repos I updated it. Since then all effects that open a UI such as overview, cube, window grid etc. just show a gray or black screen when I open them.
I am using a pinetab2 running danctnix Linux, a fork of Arch Linux ARM if I understood correctly. It comes with the default Arch Linux ARM repos plus one extra repo with pinetab2-specific fixes/packages and some extra software.
I have tried updating, rebooting, different effects, but I have no clue where to look for possible solutions/error messages for this.
Does anyone know how to fix this? If you need more info, just ask for it.
Edit/addition:
After a bit of experimenting I found out I am able to interact with the overview menu (which is the one I would mainly like to get to work again), it just does not render. I also found it does work when using x11, but I'd like to  use wayland for multiple reasons. I also found kde's log (via journalctl) gives some errors which may be usefull:
Jun 25 10:24:24 danctnix kwin_wayland[11772]: kwin_scene_opengl: 0x2: GL_INVALID_OPERATION in glVertexAttribPointer(no array object bound)
Jun 25 10:24:24 danctnix kwin_wayland[11772]: kwin_scene_opengl: 0x2: GL_INVALID_OPERATION in glVertexAttribPointer(no array object bound)
Jun 25 10:24:24 danctnix kwin_wayland[11772]: kwin_scene_opengl: 0x2: GL_INVALID_OPERATION in glDrawArrays
Jun 25 10:24:24 danctnix kwin_wayland[11772]: kwin_scene_opengl: 0x2: GL_INVALID_OPERATION in glVertexAttribPointer(no array object bound)
Jun 25 10:24:24 danctnix kwin_wayland[11772]: kwin_scene_opengl: 0x2: GL_INVALID_OPERATION in glVertexAttribPointer(no array object bound)
Jun 25 10:24:24 danctnix kwin_wayland[11772]: kwin_scene_opengl: 0x2: GL_INVALID_OPERATION in glDrawArrays
Jun 25 10:24:24 danctnix kwin_wayland[11772]: kwin_scene_opengl: 0x2: GL_INVALID_OPERATION in glVertexAttribPointer(no array object bound)
Jun 25 10:24:24 danctnix kwin_wayland[11772]: kwin_scene_opengl: 0x2: GL_INVALID_OPERATION in glVertexAttribPointer(no array object bound)
Jun 25 10:24:24 danctnix kwin_wayland[11772]: kwin_scene_opengl: 0x2: GL_INVALID_OPERATION in glDrawArrays

and that is repeated a lot of times when I try to use the overview.
